# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll in Saving IMAGE

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a form with student registration with camera using emguCV but after adding 5 or more records im experiencing a random error of An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

[image]

Comment: Just use the debugger, the Exception Assistant can show you the InnerException.  Google tells you what that exception means.  Pretty easy to run out of memory with code like this, religiously call the Image.Dispose() method and remove the jitter forcing so your program can run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Already disposing the image but still the error occured randomly.